# Single and multiline comments in emacs mode using syntax table

Tags: emacs, elisp, syntax-highlighting

I am trying to create an emacs syntax highlighting for a language in which the comments are written as

`; A single line comment`

```
;; This comment has
   multipline lines ;;
```

To do this I need to modify the entries in the syntax table. I have found that the following works perfectly for comments on multiple lines:

```
(modify-syntax-entry ?\; ". 1234" sbgl-mode-syntax-table)
```

And the following works perfectly for single line comments:

```
(modify-syntax-entry ?\; "< b" sbgl-mode-syntax-table)
(modify-syntax-entry ?\n "> b" sbgl-mode-syntax-table)
```

Does anybody know of a way to combine these?

Comment: Did you have any luck with this?

Answer (score 2):

If you can survive adding a space after each semicolon starting a single-line comment, you can treat it as an second character for one of the comment-start sequences and then here's a snippet that works for me:

```lisp
(define-derived-mode sbgl-mode prog-mode "sbgl"
  (set (make-local-variable 'font-lock-defaults)
       '(nil ;; keywords
         nil ;; keywords-only
         nil ;; case-fold
         ((?\; . ". 1234b")
          (?\n . ">")
          (?\  . "- 2")))))
```

If not, then you always have an option to do the syntactic analysis prior to fontification via `syntax-propertize-function` variable (or `font-lock-syntactic-keywords` variable for pre-Emacs24).

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like:

```
(modify-syntax-entry ?\; "< 1234b" sbgl-mode-syntax-table)
(modify-syntax-entry ?\n ">" sbgl-mode-syntax-table)
```

Comment: That's not exactly what I'm looking for. This requires any comment to end with `;;` meaning that a single line comment can begin with `;` but has to end on `;;`. Actually any comment beginning with `;` is considered to be multiline.

Comment: Indeed, that was a thinko, sorry.  You'll have to use something like `syntax-propertize-function` I'm afraid.